# Spring MVC Security - Config do Web.xml não deixa página abrir

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Estou tentando implementar o Spring Security no meu projeto, mas estou me deparando como seguinte problema.

Quando adiciono as tags ao **web.xml**, o projeto não carrega nem a pagina inicial, já inicia com erro **404**, se eu removo as tags, ele volta a carregar a pagina inicial, porém sem funcionar o `/j_spring_security_check`

Essas são as tags que fazem meu projeto parar de funcionar.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/spring-database.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Esses são os dois arquivos do `contextConfigLocation`.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/seguro**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/negado" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/home" 
        default-target-url="/seguro" 
        authentication-failure-url="/home?error" 
        username-parameter="inputEmail"
        password-parameter="inputPassword" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/home?logout"  />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=
                "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

e **spring-database.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alterei a versão do Spring de 3.1.1 para 3.2.8, o projeto agora funciona normalmente!